# how to load data from a sqlite table for several EDITTEXT

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I'm having trouble to get this data and display on an activity, can someone help me? How Can I Call DAO, and pass this data ?

all trace of classes used so far to get this problem.

Class model

```
 @DatabaseTable(tableName = "pessoa")
public class Pessoa implements EntidadePersitivel {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
     private int id;
    @DatabaseField
     private int codigo;
    @DatabaseField
     private  String nome;
    @DatabaseField
     private String cnpjCpf;


    public void setUf(String uf) {
        this.uf = uf;
    }

    @DatabaseField
     private String rgIE;
    @DatabaseField
     private String cep;
     @DatabaseField
    private String uf;
    @DatabaseField
     private String cidade;
    @DatabaseField
     private String bairro;
    @DatabaseField
     private String endereco;
    @DatabaseField
     private  String numero;
    @DatabaseField
     private String complemento;
    @DatabaseField
     private  String foneComercial;
    @DatabaseField
     private  String foneResidencial;
    @DatabaseField
     private  String foneCelular;
    @DatabaseField
     private  String email;


    public Pessoa(int id, int codigo, String nome, String cnpjCpf, String rgIE,
                  String cep, String cidade, String bairro, String endereco,
                  String numero, String complemento, String foneComercial, String foneResidencial, String foneCelular, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cnpjCpf = cnpjCpf;
        this.rgIE = rgIE;
        this.cep = cep;

        this.cidade = cidade;
        this.bairro = bairro;
        this.endereco = endereco;
        this.numero = numero;
        this.complemento = complemento;
        this.foneComercial = foneComercial;
        this.foneResidencial = foneResidencial;
        this.foneCelular = foneCelular;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Pessoa() {

    }
```

class DAO

```
  */

public class PessoaDao extends BaseDaoImpl<Pessoa, Integer> {
    public PessoaDao(ConnectionSource connectionSource) throws SQLException {
        super(Pessoa.class);
        setConnectionSource(connectionSource);
        initialize();


    }

}
```

class dataBaseHelper

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {

    private static final String dataBaseName= "central";
    private static final int version =1;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, dataBaseName, null, version);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {

        try {
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource,LoginSeralizable.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Pessoa.class);
        } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {
            TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, LoginSeralizable.class,true);
            TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Pessoa.class, true);

            onCreate(sqLiteDatabase, connectionSource);
        } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

   @Override
    public  void close(){
        super.close();
    }
}
```

error log

FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-284

```
                                                                         Process: routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante, PID: 25202
                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante.routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante.Dao.PessoaDao.queryForId(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante.DadosCadastrais$1.run(DadosCadastrais.java:49)
                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Show us what you have done?

Comment: @chiru, I added what he had done.

Comment: are you getting any exception?? If yes, then add that exception

Comment: @sanjeetkumarSingh, java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Comment: add full error log. From this single line issue can't be identified

Comment: Your error don't look like a `SQLException` , probably the problem is in another place

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro, I put this piece of code in a thread, apparent seem right, now only took another error
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro, look how is the code now.

Comment: @rodrigo.oliveira please, put the whole stack trace, if you put only this piece is impossible to guess what the is the null pointer cause

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro, I added from the model class.

Comment: @rodrigo.oliveira "Stack Trace" is the error log, the error log you posted just stop when we will find the name of the method who cause the error.

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro, i added now, sorry, but I'm new to development.

Comment: @rodrigo.oliveira No problems, i will answer your question :)

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro, a problem that just saw friend here, is that my DAO is not taking the reference of where I created this person

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127319/discussion-between-rodrigo-oliveira-and-lucas-queiroz-ribeiro).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like lucas had spoken, I reference the connection and managed

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_dados_cadastrais);
            databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(DadosCadastrais.this);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        pessoaDao = new PessoaDao(databaseHelper.getConnectionSource());
                        pessoa= pessoaDao.queryForId(1);
                        edtNome= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNome);
                        edtNome.setText(pessoa.getNome());

                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }).start();



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante.routerbox.com.br.centraisdoassinante.Dao.PessoaDao.queryForId(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

You are trying to execute the method `queryForId` in a null object, what this mean ?

The `PessoaDao` is a non static class, what means that you need to instantiate it before you can use they methods.

So you have deleted the part of your code where you call this function but if i remember right you have something like that :

`PessoaDao.queryForId('1');`

but you need to do :

```
PessoaDao pessoaDao = new PessoaDao(yourConnectionSource);
pessoaDao.queryForId('1');
```

Btw, i suppose `Pessoa` is portuguese right ? Maybe you can ask in the [Stack Overflow in portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), this way i can answer you better, and you will not need to deal with my bad english :)

Comment: The Stack Overflow community is very helper in any language, normally, is  much better post your question there

Comment: If you don't be able to solve your problem, edit your question again with the code where you call the `queryForId` and notify me, so i can update my answer

Comment: I can not, I am not able to pass my connection to DAO.

Comment: Why not ? Where you create your connection ?

Comment: I called the discussion about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127320/discussion-between-lucas-queiroz-ribeiro-and-rodrigo-oliveira).